# Implementing a dialog background image

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

using c++ under visual studio 2010.

I have a dialog creation section

```
IDD_LOGON DIALOGEX 0, 0, 265, 70
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Log On to Windows"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN 
  EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME,61,9,127,14,ES_AUTOSCROLL
  EDITTEXT        IDC_PASSWORD,61,29,127,14,ES_PASSWORD | ES_AUTOSCROLL
  EDITTEXT        IDC_DOMAIN,61,49,127,14,ES_AUTOSCROLL
  DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,204,8,50,14
  PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,204,25,50,14
  LTEXT           "Domain:",IDC_STATIC,21,52,27,8
  LTEXT           "Password:",IDC_STATIC,21,32,34,8
  LTEXT           "User Name:",IDC_STATIC,17,12,38,8
  PUSHBUTTON      "Shutdown",IDC_SHUTDOWN,204,49,50,14
END
```

I would like to have an image in the background of this dialog.

How would i go about performing this action?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick answer...  i dropped the image control on the dialog, set the image...  then...  i went into the code and placed it at the TOP of the stack, and it was painted with no issues.  the transparent portion of the other controls was failing, so i grouped them all into an area of the same background color on the image, and walla - all done.   thank you

Answer (score 4):

In your `OnInitDialog()` use:

```
this->SetBackgroundImage(IDB_BITMAP1, BACKGR_TOPLEFT, TRUE);
```

For more info refer : [CDialogEx::SetBackgroundImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983866.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this through the dialog template/designer. You will need to handle the WM_ERASEBKGND message in your dialog and paint the background yourself.

Here is some info:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18967/Bitmap-Backgrounds-For-Dialog-Boxes